# Joining data frames without returning all matching combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, purrr

I have a `list` of `data.frame`s (in this example only 2):

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,50,replace=T), val = rnorm(50), val1 = rnorm(50), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,30,replace=T), val = rnorm(30), val2 = rnorm(30), stringsAsFactors = F)

df.list <- list(df1,df2)
```

I want to `join` them into a single `data.frame` only by a subset of the shared column names, in this case by `id`.

If I use:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df.list %>% purrr::reduce(dplyr::inner_join,by="id")
```

The shared column names, which I'm not joining by, get mutated with the `x` and `y` suffices:

```
  id       val.x       val1     val.y       val2
1  G -0.05612874  0.2914462  2.087167  0.7876396
2  G -0.05612874  0.2914462 -0.255027  1.4411577
3  J -0.15579551 -0.4432919 -1.286301  1.0273924
```

In reality, for the shared column names for which I'm not joining by, it's good enough to select them from a single data.frame in the list - which ever they exist in WRT to the joined `id`.

I don't know these shared column names in advance but that's not difficult find out:

E.g.:

```
df.list.colnames <- unlist(lapply(df.list,function(l) colnames(l %>% dplyr::select(-id))))
df.list.colnames <- table(df.list.colnames)
repeating.colnames <- names(df.list.colnames)[which(df.list.colnames > 1)]
```

Which will then allow me to separate them from the `data.frame`s in the `list`:

```
repeating.colnames.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(df.list,function(r) r %>% dplyr::select_(.dots = c("id",repeating.colnames)))) %>%
  unique()
```

I can then join the list of `data.frame`s excluding these columns:

And then join them as above:

```
for(r in 1:length(df.list)) df.list[[r]] <- df.list[[r]] %>% dplyr::select_(.dots = paste0("-",repeating.colnames))
df <- df.list %>% purrr::reduce(dplyr::inner_join,by="id")
```

And now I'm left with adding the `repeating.colnames.df` to that. I don't know of any `join` in `dplyr` that wont return all combinations between `df` and `repeating.colnames.df`, so it seems that all I can do is `apply` over each `df$id`, pick the first match in `repeating.colnames.df` and join the result with `df`.

Is there anything less cumbersome for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed correctly, I think you can handle this by writing a custom function to pass into `reduce` that identifies the common column names (excluding your joining columns) and excludes those columns from the "second" table in the merge. As `reduce` works through the list, the function will "accumulate" the unique columns, defaulting to the columns in the "left-most" table.

Something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,50,replace=T), val = rnorm(50), val1 = rnorm(50), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,30,replace=T), val = rnorm(30), val2 = rnorm(30), stringsAsFactors = F)
df.list <- list(df1,df2)

fun <- function(df1, df2, by_col = "id"){
  df1_names <- names(df1)
  df2_names <- names(df2)
  dup_cols <- intersect(df1_names[!df1_names %in% by_col], df2_names[!df2_names %in% by_col])
  out <- dplyr::inner_join(df1, df2[, !(df2_names %in% dup_cols)], by = by_col)
  return(out)
}

df_chase <- df.list %>% reduce(fun,by_col="id")
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

If I compare `df_chase` to your final solution, I yield the same answer:

```r
> all.equal(df_chase, df_orig)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of the duplicate columns from one of the data frames if you say you don't really care about them and simply use `base::merge`:

```
set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,50,replace=T), val = rnorm(50), val1 = rnorm(50), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(id = sample(LETTERS,30,replace=T), val = rnorm(30), val2 = rnorm(30), stringsAsFactors = F)


duplicates = names(df1) == names(df2) & names(df1) !="id"

df2 = df2[,!duplicates]
df12 = base::merge.data.frame(df1, df2, by = "id")
head(df12)
```

Comment: Thanks @Al J Abadi but the question is more about a scenario of joining a list of `data.frame`s. The example only includes 2 `data.frame`s since it is a toy example.